# Error when trying to get data from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

when I try to retrieve a data from firestore with this code.

```
Future<String> getUserType() async {
        await (Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document(getUserUID().toString())
            .get()
            .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
          return ds['type'];
        }));
      }
```

i get this error

```
 NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
 I/flutter (15824): Receiver: null
 I/flutter (15824): Tried calling: []("type")
```

I also tried:

```
return ds.data['type'];
```

The code to retrive the uid of user is:

```
Future<String> getUserUID() async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser()).uid;
  }
```

but I don't think that this is the problem, maybe in ds there is nothing.

Comment: what if the user has no documents?

Normally, you get the list of documents for a given user, then you check if the data is not null, post which you loop through them and check the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the `userID` first and then use that in your document retrieval:

```
Future<String> getUserType() async {
String userID = (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser()).uid;
        await (Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document(userID)
            .get()
            .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
          return ds['type'];
        }));
      }
```

---

In your code:

```
Future<String> getUserUID() async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser()).uid;
  }
```

`getUserUID()` returns a `Future`, but when you do `.document(getUserUID().toString())` you are not getting the result of that `Future`.

Check the following:

https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Answer (score 0):

Your getUserUID() method returns a Future String not a regular String.So that you cannot directly get a document by providing that.This is the usual way I implement a function like this.

```
Future<String> getUserType() async {
 getUserUID().then((currentUser) {
  if (currentUser != null) {
    await (Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(currentUser)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      return ds['type'];
    }));
   }
   }
  }
```